Non-metrizable countably-dimensional, complete, separable, sequential, Hausdorff, locally convex topological vector space, not Fréchet–Urysohn, not N1
Which topological vector space is non-metrizable, countably-dimensional, complete, sequentially separable (hence separable), sequential, Hausdorff, locally convex topological vector space, not Fréchet–Urysohn, not N1?
Also, other useful examples of countably-dimensional Hausdorff topological vector spaces are appreciated.

$\pmb{\mathbb K^\infty}$ is a non-metrizable, countably-dimensional, complete, sequentially separable (hence separable), sequential, Hausdorff, locally convex topological vector space, not Fréchet–Urysohn, not N1
$\mathbb K$ may be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.
$\mathbb K^\infty:=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\in\mathbb K^\mathbb N\,\colon\, $all but finitely many $x_i$ equal $0\}$ = the space of finite sequences over $\mathbb K$, equipped with the "final topology", the finest topology that makes inclusions from each $\mathbb K^n$ continuous.
Proof: By Wikipedia, $\mathbb K^\infty$ is complete, Hausdorff, locally convex, sequential, topological vector space that is not Fréchet–Urysohn (i.e., some subsets have a non-closed sequential closure). But N1 TVSs are metrizable, so $\mathbb K^\infty$ is not N1.
The set $\mathbb Q^\infty$ of finite sequences over rational numbers is countable and dense (because each $\mathbb K^n\subset\mathbb K^\infty$ has its original topology, making $\mathbb Q^n$ sequentially dense in it), even sequentially dense (every $x\in\mathbb R^\infty$ is the limit of a sequence in $\mathbb Q^\infty$). Use $\mathbb Q^\infty+i\mathbb Q^\infty$ for $\mathbb C^\infty$, QED.
Notes: $c_{00}$ is the same space with the supremum norm. It is a (sequentially) separable, incomplete, countably-dimensional, normed space. Therefore, $c_{00}$ is N1, N2, metrizable, Fréchet–Urysohn, sequential, Hausdorff, locally convex topological vector space.
